# Scala add members to base class

Tags: scala

I need to support multiple keyboard layouts in my application.

This is one solution, but in Scala I suspect there's a better way that would allow me to use use `KeyLayout` variables directly, such as typing `KeyLayout.KEY_HOME` instead of `get_keycodes(12)("KEY_HOME")`. Is this possible? If I use a Map like the code below, then my other code constantly has to check that each key code I want to use actually exists, with code like `get_keycodes(12).contains("KEY_HOME")`. It would be much better if `get_keycodes(12)` returned an object with a number of `val KEY_FOO = KeyCode(x)` items, so that you could do stuff like `get_keycodes(12).KEY_HOME` and have the compiler ensure that this is going to work

```
case class KeyCode(key: Int)

object `KeyLayout_v12` extends KeyLayout {
  val keys = Map("KEY_HOME" -> KeyCode(0x007a))
}

object `KeyLayout_v15.2` extends KeyLayout {
  val keys = Map("KEY_HOME" -> KeyCode(0x003a))
}

class KeyLayout

object KeyLayout {

  // Gets the default keycodes for version you are using
  def getKeycodes(version: Double): Map[String, KeyLayout] = androidVersion match {
      case 12 => `KeyLayout_v12`.keys
      case 15.2 => `KeyLayout_v15.2`.keys
      case _ => {
        info(s"Unknown $version, returning keycodes for 12")
        `KeyLayout_v12`.keys
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think type classes is what you need (edited my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use type classes (anyway you should know or assume androidVesion in compile time):

```
trait Version
object v12 extends Version
object v15_2 extends Version

class Layout[T <: Version]

implicit class v12layout(v: Layout[v12.type]) {    
        val KEY_HOME = 100500
}

implicit class v15_2layout(v: Layout[v15_2.type]) {
        val KEY_HOME = 100600
        val KEY_A = 300900
}

def getLayout[T <: Version](v: T) = new Layout[T]

getLayout(v15_2).KEY_HOME
```

Usage:

```
scala> getLayout(v12).KEY_HOME
res4: Int = 100500

scala> getLayout(v15_2).KEY_HOME
res5: Int = 100600

scala> getLayout(v12).KEY_A
<console>:20: error: value KEY_A is not a member of Layout[v12.type]
          getLayout(v12).KEY_A
                         ^

scala> getLayout(v15_2).KEY_A
res7: Int = 300900
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use nested Map? `val keyLayouts = Map[Double, Map[String, KeyCode]]`, then get a version with `keyLayouts.get(12).map(_.keys).getOrElse(//throw error or return default)`.

Not sure I really understand the question though.

Update:

If you want to access KEY_HOME as though it where a method/value, then you have to make it so. Or you could use `Symbol`s, then you could do `keyLayouts(12)('KEY_HOME)`.

Still dont really understand the point of the question though, also dont understand why you include `getKeycodes` in your snippet as it seems irrelevant.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using anything like `Map[String, KeyCode]`, and instead be able to return an object that has a number of `val KEY_FOO = KeyCode(xxx)` members. This would means that all `KeyCode` uses are checked at compile time, and you don't have to constantly check (in one way or another) if your map contains a `KeyCode`, e.g. `keyMap.contains("KEY_HOME")`

Comment: Basically, I'd like to replace `keyLayouts.get(12).map(_.keys).getOrElse(//throw error or return default)` with something like `keyLayouts.get(12).KEY_HOME`

Comment: What I want to do should be pretty clear - I want to rely on the compiler to see if the class members exist. Problem is that the entire concept of adding new info to a class definition is new to me - in other languages I'd just use the Map (as both you and I recommended), so perhaps I'm just thinking that Scala can magically do something other languages cannot, or I just don't know enough about the concept to ask the question using the right terms

Comment: The rules for picking the "correct" KeyLayout are much more complex than what I'm presenting here, so I can't just repeat the logic to choose the proper subclass everywhere. Typically this is solved with polymorphism, but I'm not keen to repeat an entire default `KeyLayout` in the base class. If there's no better Scala answer then I'll just make my base class be the implementation of the most common `KeyLayout_vFooBar`. That would make my base class have all the members needed and I can override them as needed. I'm just hoping for a more idiomatic method

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that was not mentioned is [`scala.Dynamic`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic) trait. It allows to call  arbitrary methods on an instance of type marked `Dynamic` by transforming them to appropriate `applyDynamic`, `selectDynamic` or `updateDynamic` method invocation. Following example demonstrates possible solution.

```
case class Key(name: String, code: Int)

sealed trait Version
sealed trait v12 extends Version
sealed trait v15_2 extends Version

sealed trait KeyLayout[T <: Version] extends Dynamic {

  def keys: Set[Key]

  def selectDynamic(name: String): Option[Key] =
    keys.find(_.name == name)
}

object KeyLayout {

  def apply[V <: Version: KeyLayout] = implicitly[KeyLayout[V]]

  implicit object `12` extends KeyLayout[v12] {
    val keys = Set(Key("KEY_HOME", 0x007a))
  }

  implicit object `15_2` extends KeyLayout[v15_2] {
    val keys = Set(Key("KEY_HOME", 0x003a))
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
scala> KeyLayout[v15_2].KEY_HOME
res2: Option[Key] = Some(Key(KEY_HOME,58))

scala> KeyLayout[v12].KEY_FOO
res3: Option[Key] = None
```

Comment: there is no compile-time check for no KEY_F00 in that case. Also, there is no reason to store keys in Set instead of Map (O(N) vs O(1)). selectDynamic (even with Map) will be little bit slower.

Comment: and if you use dynamics - you don't really need implicits (code may be rewritten without) and don't need constant values for versions, because at least key extraction actually moving to runtime. There is no difference in usage between dynamic-based KeyLayout[v12].KEY_FOO and just KeyLayout(12.0)("KEY_FOO").

Comment: @dk14, agreed. It is just an example of `Dynamic` usage. My intention was to show different approach.